# Ошибка при публикации

Tags: .net, .net-core

Пытаюсь опубликовать консольное приложение .Net Core 3.0 и ловлю ошибку:

> 27.11.2019 14:36:40 System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Publishing failed.    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.d__23.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.d__202.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publishing failed.<---
>
> System.Exception: Publishing failed.
>
> ===================

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если через консоль собирать `dotnet publish -r win-x64`, то ошибки про обнаружение понижения версии пакета...:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С чем она может быть связана?

Answer (score 1):

Она может быть связана с тем, что разные библиотеки, используемые приложением, в свою очередь используют разные версии одного и того же пакета. Выполните консолидацию пакетов для вашего решения с помощью: `(RKM) контекстное меню решения -> Управление пакетами Nuget для решения -> Консолидировать`